# Minecraft: Give items depending on player's score

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

so lets say I have a score named `amount` with a score of 30.

So I was making a command that will give me items depending on the score of `amount`

for example, the score of `amount` is 30, then it will give me 30 items of what item I decided.

Any commands, forex.: `/execute` or `something?`

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: yea I tried..I just can't do it..

Comment: Can you add the things you tried to your question?

Comment: If this is like `batch` like i could do this instead: `give @p diamond %amount% 0` I would've answered my own question XD

Comment: I can do it one by one using `/execute` but I can't do that way many command blocks it's way too tiring.

Comment: like this: `@execute @a[score_amount_min=1,score_amount=1] ~ ~ ~ give @a[score_amount_min=1,score_amount=1] log 1 3`

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to insert a scoreboard value in a command in the way that you described it in your comments, but you can do it like this:

```
/give @a[score_amount_min=1] SOME_ITEM 0
/scoreboard players remove @a[score_amount_min=1] amount 1
```

These commands should be looped.
This gives all players with a score on the amount scoreboard one item until the counter reaches 0.

You might also want to tag players with a certain tag, so that you can control when the items are given.

```
/scoreboard tag add SOME_PLAYER givemeitems
```

Then you change the target selectors in the previous commands to: `@a[score_amount_min=1,tag=givemeitems]`

That should do everything you want.

Comment: ...and those two commands should be in a loop.

Comment: @Fabian good point! I forgot to mention that. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Now in 1.13 you could use a scoreboard value as a stack size, but only if you know the stack index (not the slot number), which is pretty complicated.